# BMC Footprints Python SOAP API call w/ Kerberos user authentication

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, soap, kerberos

I'm attempting to make Footprints calls using their API with a python script. BMC has great documentation on how to make Perl/PHP/Java calls against their API, but no documentation for Python.

I did however find a nice script, that creates a "footprints" module, and assists calling the SOAP API: 
https://github.com/cmemery/footprints

However, I must use a base64 encoded MIKE Kerberos service ticket as my authentication method , I cannot use Username/Password combination.

As such, I have not found any good documentation on how to preform calls like this against the Footprints application, are there any ideas on what I could do better?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that Footprints API only accepts Basic Auth, at least in 12.1. From the BMC documentation (https://docs.bmc.com/docs/display/public/FPSC121/Configuring+Web+Services):

"First, you enable Web Services for your system and then enable access to the Services for specific Agent and Customer roles. *Only the FootPrints internal authentication method is supported*."

and, from the [API Docs](https://docs.bmc.com/docs/download/attachments/495323458/API%20Web%20Services%20definitions.pdf?version=2&modificationDate=1463398670569&api=v2)

"FootPrints Service Core Web Services uses Basic authentication (BA). The user name and password are sent in the HTTP header. SSL communication is required to protect user credentials."

I spent a good amount of time failing to connect till I had our FP admin create a local FP service account for connecting to the api.

I should be pushing an update to the script you linked as well that supports 12.1, since it broke when we upgraded. Hope that helps.